# form element didn't handle javascript changes

Tags: javascript, forms

I have element `<form>` on a page. Inside form there are fields, that must be filled by user. When page scrolled to the end I am deleting part of the text with JavaScript *(`deleteUslessTextFromForm()` method works, just trust)* and sending data on server

```
  deleteUslessTextFromForm();
  var formElement = document.getElementById('form');
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  await request.open("POST", url);
  await request.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

The problem is: data that sends to server is a data which were before JS script deletion and it mean that form doesn't handle changes of it's own fields. And when I get element by id it have text before deletion.

How can I solve this bug?

For example:
[All that underlined with red color is added by "Mark the paragraph" btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5fxK.png)

[When scrolling to the bottom script doing such "magic"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0I1k.png)

But when trying to send data on server gets data from first screenshot

[working code of deleteUslessTextFromForm()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC11l.png)

[here is an HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c0Tx.png)

Comment: I think your problem might be in `deleteUselessTextFromForm()`. Are you clearing the field values with something like `fieldElement.val('')`?

Comment: @EddieReeder no, actually when user enters text into text area it becomes like `<p>text</p>`,  with previous app logic I am adding `div` with className to this `p` element. `deleteUselessTextFromForm()` - it is a method that doing something like `let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(someId); elements.map(el => el.remove());`

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you to read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question. In order to get an answer you need to provide more information such as: 1) A working example of your code, if possible wrapped in a code snippet, 2) Any solutions that you tried until now, 3) Screenshots or references that can help the community to understand and visualize your problem

Comment: @vmank is it ok now?

Comment: Screenshots definitely help but without the full code(HMTL, CSS, JS) we can't track down where the problem is.

Comment: @vmank add all that I can